# Reducing ac voltage from 19,2VAC to 18VAC

Tags: ac

My trafo has  a secondary voltage 19,3V and 125 VA. I want to reduce the voltage to 18V. What is the easiest way?
Storm

Comment: What are you feeding with it? Depending on your trafo/load the voltage might drop well below that when something is connected.

Comment: From 19.3 V to 18 V is a reduction of about 7 %. I'm assuming this is a mains transformer. The mains voltage can easily vary 10% so what would then be the point of reducing the voltage by 7% given that the mains voltage variation alone can give you a voltage below 18 V ?

Comment: I am feeding modeltrain boosters, wich need at least 52VA each

Answer (score 1):

Let it be if that 7 percent overvoltage is not harmful in your application.  If it is then put 2 double diodes in series. Double diode=2 in parallel, directions = opposite. You will dissipate that 7% so be sure to have 2.5A types and proper cooling. As already proposed, the voltage drop may do the job without any intervention.

Comment: also note, there will be an extended zero wave based on the forward voltage of the diode

Answer (score 1):

Use Resistor to drop desired voltage...As we know `v = I*R` thus you can get value of Resistance and You can reduce your `AC` voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you refer to unloaded voltages and can contenplate rewinding your transformer, I would suggest the following:

Count the number of turns on the secondary = Ns. Divide with 19.3. Multiply with 18. Subtract from original number. Remove that number of turns from the secondary. That will set the new unloaded voltage to 18 Vac with the new number of turns = Ns*(19.3/18).

Under load, the voltage may sag significantly depending on your transformer design.